# How to remove space at beginning and end of a string in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

using Dart How to remove space at the beginning and end of a string?

```
 String name =" Well Wisher ";
```

or this

```
 String name =" Well Wisher";
```

or from this

```
String name ="Well Wisher ";
```

Comment: Its called trim

Comment: Use the ``trim()`` method. ``name = name.trim();``

Comment: I made a mistake on my answer. `trim()` will remove all trailing and leading white spaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5882307/omi-shah
the .trim() function is used to remove white space from the front and end of a string

```
String name =" Well Wisher ";

name.trim();  // "Well Wisher"
```