I try to display a text from flutter bluetooth but the length is 'wrong'
await characteristic?.read().then((value) {
    String decoded = utf8.decode(value);
    print('value: $decoded');
    print('!!! ${decoded.length}');
  }

Prints:
!!! fetchDeviceName value: name
!!! 32

When I try do display my decoded value in my UI I want to show 'name' but the text display name with a bunch of empty space behind it. How can I solve this?
I tried to add a dot behind the name and I get:
"name           ."


This looks like the device pads its value to some length (this isn't anything about Bluetooth; it's the specific device you're communicating with). If you don't want that, you'll need to trim the string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64399756/how-to-remove-space-at-beginning-and-end-of-a-string-in-dart/64836321 Or investigate the documentation for this device to see if there is a length byte provided.
